# Show there are 1977 non-similar triangles such that$\frac{\sin X+\sin Y+\sin Z}{\cos X+\cos Y+\cos Z}=\frac{12}7$and$\sin X\sin Y\sin Z=\frac{12}{25}$

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

> Show that there are 1977 non-similar triangles whose angles $X$, $Y$, $Z$ satisfy the conditions
> $$\begin{align}
> \frac{\sin{X}+ \sin{Y}+ \sin{Z}}{\cos{X}+\cos{Y}+ \cos{Z}}=\frac{12}{7} \tag1\\[4pt]
> \sin{X}\sin{Y} \sin{Z}=\frac{12}{25} \tag2
> \end{align}$$

My attempt: $$\begin{align} \sin{X}+ \sin{Y}+ \sin{Z}=4\cos{\frac{X}{2}} \cos{\frac{Y}{2}} \cos{\frac{Z}{2}} \\ \cos{X}+ \cos{Y}+ \cos{Z}=1+4\sin{\frac{X}{2}} \sin{\frac{Y}{2}} \sin{\frac{Z}{2}}\\ X+Y+Z=\pi \\ \sin{X} \sin{Y}\sin{Z}=8\cos{\frac{X}{2}} \cos{\frac{Y}{2}} \cos{\frac{Z}{2}}\sin{\frac{X}{2}} \sin{\frac{Y}{2}} \sin{\frac{Z}{2}}=\frac{12}{25}\end{align}$$ Here after what to do to find the required results.

How to show such points which satisfy these conditions?

Please, help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: i think it is  question from the vietnamese Mathe olympiad (maybe i am wrong)

Comment: Well, you could solve for $\sin{\frac{X}{2}} \sin{\frac{Y}{2}} \sin{\frac{Z}{2}}$ and for $\cos{\frac{X}{2}} \cos{\frac{Y}{2}} \cos{\frac{Z}{2}}$ and if my calculations are correct, you have to solve this system of equations.https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2Bsin%28y%29%2Bsin%28x%2By%29%3D12%2F5+and+cos%28x%29%2Bcos%28y%29-cos%28x%2By%29%3D7%2F5 after changing product to sum and writing $Z=\pi-X-Y$.

Comment: And if you notice the values of $\sin(X)$ are $0.6, 0.8, 1$. Maybe this would be helpful.

Comment: @–user35508 From this solution how can we say there are exactly 1977 non similar triangles?

Comment: @Chris And this is the part that confuses me ...There is nothing in my solution that could lead to $1977$ triangles. In fact, it only gives a $3,4,5$ triangle only.

Comment: Where do the 1977 come from??? I found only ONE right triangle with acute angles having sine $\frac{3}{5};\;\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: Question is we need to find non-similar triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard notation,
given $\triangle ABC$ with angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$,
side lengths $a,b,c$, semiperimeter $\rho$,
radius  $r$ of the inscribed circle,
and radius  $R$ of the circumscribed circle,

\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\alpha+ \sin\beta+ \sin\gamma}
{\cos\alpha+ \cos\beta+ \cos\gamma}
&=\frac{12}{7}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma
&=\frac{12}{25}
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Using known identities,

\begin{align}
\sin\alpha+ \sin\beta+ \sin\gamma
&=
\frac\rho R=u
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\cos\alpha+ \cos\beta+ \cos\gamma
&=
\frac rR+1=v+1
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma
&=
\frac{\rho r}{2R^2}=\tfrac12\,uv
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

we ca rewrite \eqref{1}-\eqref{2}
in terms of parameters $u=\rho/R,\,v=r/R$ as

\begin{align}
\frac u{v+1}&=\frac{12}{7}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
\tfrac12\,uv
&=\frac{12}{25}
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

The system \eqref{6}-\eqref{7}
has just two solutions,

\begin{align} 
u &= -\frac{24}{35},\quad v = -\frac75
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
u &= \frac{12}5,\quad v =\frac25
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}

and obviously, only positive is valid,
so, there is only one type of triangle with given properties.

Solution of the cubic equation
\begin{align} 
x^3-2u\,x^2+(u^2+v^2+4v)\,x-4uv
&=0
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
x^3-\frac{24}5\,x^2+\frac{188}{25}\,x-\frac{96}{25}
&=0
\tag{11}\label{11}
\end{align}

gives a unique triplet of side lengths of triangle
with $R=1$,
which satisfies \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}

\begin{align} 
a&=\frac65,\quad b=\frac85,\quad c=2
\tag{12}\label{12}
.
\end{align}

As we can see, this triangle is similar to the famous $3-4-5$
right-angled triangle.

Indeed, we have
\begin{align} 
\sin\alpha&=\frac35,\quad\sin\beta=\frac45,\quad\sin\gamma=1
\tag{13}\label{13}
,\\
\cos\alpha&=\frac45,\quad\cos\beta=\frac35,\quad\cos\gamma=0
\tag{14}\label{14}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma
&=
\frac{12}5
\tag{15}\label{15}
,\\
\cos\alpha+ \cos\beta+ \cos\gamma
&=
\frac75
\tag{16}\label{16}
,\\
\frac{\sin\alpha+ \sin\beta+ \sin\gamma}
{\cos\alpha+ \cos\beta+ \cos\gamma}
&=\frac{12}{7}
\tag{17}\label{17}
,\\
\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma
&=
\frac{12}{25}
\tag{18}\label{18}
.
\end{align}

Comment: Right, but there's an issue. See problem A2 here : https://prase.cz/kalva/vietnam/viet77.html I think there's been a possible wrong translation from Vietnamese or something, for there's no way the statement given there can be true.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon:Agree, it must be a tricky question,
when you need to prove that the question is not correct.

Comment: Very roughly speaking, unless the two given condition collapses into one another, there is a unique solution as a triangle is, up to similarity, uniquely determined by $2$ angles. I think there must be some requirement such as angles are rational multiples of $\pi$ and a typo with the given equation.

Comment: @dezdichado: or, perhaps, these are inequalities
and the side lengths supposed to be integral.

Comment: @Chris:
["Two triangles, △ABC and △A′B′C′, are similar if and only if corresponding angles have the same measure: this implies that they are similar if and only if the lengths of corresponding sides are proportional"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_(geometry)#Similar_triangles),
so 3:4:5 and 6:8:10 are similar, since they have the same angles.
The mysterious 1977 number is either a mistake/mistranslation,
or a distraction part of the tricky question.

Comment: @ g.kov Thank you for clearing my doubt.